# Insert not working, but select finds the data on same page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm inserting a simple entry into a database-table using PDO (php/mysql). The connection is set up correctly and it seems that the data is inserted. Later on the same page (after the insertion) I call a select statement to get all data from that table. It returns everything, including the newly inserted column (and it's incremented id).

But when I refresh the site - or just have a look at the table in phpmyadmin - the new entry is gone... And there is no delete code yet.

Here is the code for insertion

```
// prep statement   
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO garage (created_at, created_by, modified_at, modified_by, caption, description, picture) VALUES (:created_at, :created_by, :modified_at, :modified_by, :caption, :description, :picture);");

// binding params, all rows return true
$stmt->bindParam(":created_at", $ts, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":created_by", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":modified_at", $ts, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":modified_by", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":caption", $caption, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":description", $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":picture", $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute(); // returns true
```

A few lines of code later:

```
$selStmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, caption, description, picture FROM garage;");
$selStmt->execute();

while ($row = $selStmt->fetchObject()) {
  echo $row->id; // output is working, id is next increment
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: Awk, yep. Didn't thought about thank. Thanks!

Comment: lol was that the problem then?

Comment: just forgot $pdo->commit();